# Regex to check all occurrences of specific letters be capital

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern that follows the rules:

1. All occurrence of the letters E, I, L must be capital strictly.
2. All other letters must strictly be lowercase.

I'm working with this rule `^[^eil]*[eil][^eil]*$` but having all capital letters also accepts the string.

Comment: `/^(?:[[a-z]--[eil]]|[EIL])*$/v`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I'm not able to reproduce this with the v flag on my react app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use a match for only `E` `I` `L`, lowercase chars a-z without `e` `i` `l` plus digits `_` and non word characters `\W`

```
^[EILabcdfghjkm-z0-9_\W]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MknkUZ/1)

Comment: I found this did not work as OP asked

Comment: @FuzzoftheInterwebs The OP accepted the answer, I don't know what you mean by that either.

Comment: use `EdIt thE Ls` as an example. put a uppercase non-EIL character on the front and it fails

Comment: @FuzzoftheInterwebs That is the expected behaviour as also stated in the comment under your answer `I want other letters to be strictly lower case`

Comment: Furthering the example, the string `SEdIt thE Ls` violates Rule 2 since S is not meant to be uppercase.
Okay, I must have messed some thing up. It does WORK like it should

Answer (score 1):

The statement of the question does not preclude the string from containing any characters other than letters. One option is to employ negation, by matching the regular expression

```
^(?!.*[eilA-DF-HJKM-Z]).*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/67IMbs/1)

---

If the expression is to only be used to test the assertion that the string contains no letters in `"eilABCDFGHJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`, `.*` at the end can be dropped. That token is included to return the entire string if the lookahead assertion is satisfied.

---

The expression can be broken down as follows:

```
^                  match the beginning of the string
(?!                begin a negative lookahead
  .*               match >= 0 chars other than line terminators
  [eilA-DF-HJKM-Z] match one of the chars in the character class
)                  end the negative lookahead 
.*                 match >= 0 chars other than line terminators
```

Answer (score 0):

`/^[^eil]*[EIL][^eil]*$/g` appears to work on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) using the string: `EdIt thE ExprEssIon & tExt to sEE matchEs.L`
Changing E, I or L to lowercase will not match any more, as you are expecting.

Notably, you must be running the operation in a case sensitive manner. Since you are doing case sensitive operations, you need `[EIL]` in the regex string to find those uppercase letters.

Comment: `EDIT THE EXPRESSION` string is also accepted with this pattern, I want other letters to be strictly lower case.

Comment: It matches because the first letter is uppercase. Need to work around that, I'll post an update

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use this regex:

```
^(?:[EIL]|[^A-Zeil])+$
```

Which will match either:

- `[EIL]` : the letters `E`, `I` or `L`; or
- `[^A-Zeil]` : anything other than a capital letter or `e`, `i` or `l`

The first half of the alternation will match `E`, `I` or `L`, and if the current character is not one of those then it is tested against the second half of the alternation, which allows lowercase letters which are not `e`, `i` or `l` and any other characters.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GHFpDP/2)

Comment: This is wrong because?

Comment: It isn't wrong but being regex there is more than one answer. This is much cleaner since it uses more functionality